# How can I track down what is giving my desktop spam notifications?

Tags: 18.04, malware

I'm getting desktop notifications when I log in. They look simply like news headlines. I thought they were some new part of Ubuntu. Clicking on these leads me to websites like **investing-review.com** with spammy bitcoin-related content pretending to be the BBC.

I don't think I've installed anything which would do this, so I'm puzzled.

I tried running

```
ps -ef
```

To see what was running, but the list is huge and nothing obvious jumps out. I'd prefer not to have to reinstall everything, but get to the bottom of this by finding the root cause and removing that.

EDIT: Although I've now worked out what was causing this, it was only by guesswork. It would still be very useful to know how to debug this kind of problem in future.

Comment: Would guess something in your browser, do a total purge and then reinstall.  Pickup something from a website, would also add an adblocker(ublock) after.

Comment: Instead of clicking on unknown links, should do a google(or another) search of them.  Clicking links is a good way to get malware.

Comment: Before reinstalling your browser you can export all your bookmarks. Then import them after reinstall.

Comment: Ubuntu itself is usually safe from malware, but the browsers can still be infected.  The easiest way to clean is a reinstall of that browser.  An adblocker extension would also be a good idea to do after.  It is probably some type of admalware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as it turned out was Firefox. I use Mozilla Sync, so my bookmarks, etc were already backed up. To remove Firefox I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox*
```

To be safe I moved my .mozilla folder to a backup.

Then after a reboot, I did:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

Then I logged back into Sync and changed my password. Once I could see I had what I needed, I deleted the backup of .mozilla. Thanks to those who posted suggestions, they were helpful and I've upvoted them.

Answer (score 3):

Find the browser that is sending the spam notifications and disable them. For firefox, open firefox and got to the address `about:preferences#general` (or go to preferences from the rightmost small button on the top with the three lines). Then on the search box that says 'find in preferences' type `notifications` then set everything to `block`. Re-enable stuff you like, such as your email.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to go into settings -> notifications on Ubuntu, and disable all notifications, or based on application. If you try disabling "Google Chrome" then restarting to force the condition for popups to appear, you could check if it's actually from the browser you get the notifications.

If notifications still persist, it's something else, try toggling the other options.

If it is Chrome, paste this into chrome URL bar: 
`chrome://settings/content/notifications`

[Click here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for Google Chrome notification support page

And tweak which sites are allowed to send you push notifications through Chrome.
A re-install of chrome could potentially gain you nothing if you're logged in to the browser with a user, as the settings usually sync to the account.